# Jersey cannot unmarshall java.lang.Number

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a generic (POJO-)container to share statistical data with clients:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class StatsSeries implements Serializable {

    private TreeMap<Date, Number> timeSeries;

    /* accessor methods */
}
```

Depending on the data, the server stores `Long`, `Integer` or `Double` in it, which is why I'm using abstract `java.lang.Number`.

Marshalling works fine, and hints indicating the concrete class are included in the data:

```
            "timeSeries": {
                "entry": [
                    {
                        "key": "2012-08-20T00:00:00Z", 
                        "value": {
                            "$": "24", 
                            "@type": "xs:long"
                        }
                    }, 
                    ....
                 ]
              }
```

Or in XML representation:

```
    <timeSeries>
      <entry>
        <key>2012-08-20T00:00:00Z</key>
        <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:long">24</value>
      </entry>
      ...
    </timeSeries>
```

When attempting to unmarshall this, I get an `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of java.lang.Number`.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688878/java-web-services-jaxb-abstract-superclass), but it doesn't help me. How can I annotate `java.lang.Number`? Any other suggestions?

**Update**: Looking at [JAXB-890](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-890), I understand that it should be fixed either on JDK 1.7 or using `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6` -- neither works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work given type-erasure, but you might try [annotating with `XmlElementRef`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html)

```
    @XmlElementRef
    private TreeMap<Date, Number> timeSeries;
```

> "when this annotation is used, the XML element name is derived from the instance of the type of the JavaBean property at runtime".

Failing that, see [if this link helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941479/jaxb-how-to-marshall-map-into-keyvalue-key).