# Java8 cannot use wsgen with a webservice endpoint that extends another class (Works with Java7)

Tags: web-services, wsdl, java-8, jax-ws, wsgen

I'm trying to use wsgen to generate wsdl files. If my webservice class extends another class I get an error but if I remove the extends it works. This is the error message:

```
error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported
```

Also wsgen -fullversion:

```
wsgen full version "JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#8c29a9a53251ff741fca1664a8221dc876b2eac8"
```

Please note that I only have this problem when I use Java8. But the same code works when I use Java 7, and wsgen -version:

```
JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
```

Here is more details and how to reproduce it:
I'm using Java8 and I have three files:

```
webservice
    basewebservice.java
    webservice.java
    webserviceImpl.java
```

basewebservice.java:

> package webservice;
>
> public class basewebservice { }

webservice.java

> package webservice;
>
> import javax.jws.WebMethod; import javax.jws.WebService;
>
> @WebService 
>   public interface webservice {
>
> @WebMethod
>     public String hello();
>
> }

webserviceImpl.java

> package webservice;
>
> import javax.jws.WebService;
>
> @WebService(endpointInterface="webservice.webservice",
>   serviceName="webservice")
>
> public class webserviceImpl **extends basewebservice**
>            implements  webservice {
>       @Override
>       public String hello() {
>           return "heLLoo";
>       } 
>   }

I use this command to generate wsdl file:

```
wsgen -cp "." webservice.webserviceImpl -r . -wsdl
```

It only works when I remove the **extends basewebservice**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an @XMLSeeAlso annotation on the BaseWebService. Check out this question - [Java Web Services/JAXB - Abstract superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688878/java-web-services-jaxb-abstract-superclass)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right approach, When I change to Java 7 it works. (I'll update the question)